# Android - determining when a thread has finished executing

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm in a bit of a bind. I am writing an application with a Progress Dialog that updates its value. I was following this tutorial on how to make one and I ended up with this code:

```
progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage("Scanning for Devices");
progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
progress.setProgress(0);
progress.show();

final int totalProgressTime = 100;
final Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int jumpTime = 0;
        BTAdapter.startDiscovery();

        while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
            try {
                sleep(250);
                jumpTime += 5;
                progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
t.start();
```

But now, when the progress hits 100, the `while()` loop no longer executes and now I can't quite know programatically if the progress is done or not. Code-wise, the Thread will just run until the progress hits 100. Unlike the Async Task where I have a `postExecute` function, the Thread does not seem to have a function to stop itself and tell you (an override or a listener) that it's done executing.

Does anyone know how to know when the thread has stopped executing its task or call an outside function when its task is done?

I tried to call a function `onExecuteAfter` after the `while` loop to update my UI thread but that was futile.

Comment: *the Thread does not seem to have a function to stop*: The execution ends with the end of the method run. *or call an outside function when its task is done* There is no such a thing. You have to implement it on your own.

Comment: use activity.runOnUiThread() if you want to execute a code on ui from a non ui thread

Comment: Rxjava may hit your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably now know, you can't really do UI work in a non-UI thread.

The usual approach in these situations is to use a context or a handler to post a Runnable when the thread is done:

```
    // Created in UI thread as a local instance variable in
    // the Fragment or Activity
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    ....

    @Override
    public void run() {
         ....
         while(...) {
             ....stuff...
         }
         mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             void run() {
                 ... do something useful in the UI thread ...
             }
         });
     }
```

If you want to you can make the Runnable a local member in the host fragment or activity, and remember that all View objects have a post(Runnable) method that you can use instead of a Handler if that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // Handle 'doInBackground' work here
    while(jumpTime < totalProgressTime) {
        try {
            sleep(250);
            jumpTime += 5;
            progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Handle 'postExecute' work here.
    doUiWork();
}

private void doUiWork() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    });
}
```